# Why do I get literal \r and \n when getting text from a database using C#?

Tags: c#, string

In a database field, I'm storing and returning the "body" of my email (in case it changes). In this I have \n\r characters to get new lines. But, it seems not to be working. Any thoughts:

So data in field:

```
'TBD.\r\n\nExpect'
```

And my output looks like (literal \r and \n):

```
TBD.\r\n\nExpect
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Wait, I'm confused. Are you using `\n\r` or `\r\n`?

Comment: \r should come before \n. Think of the old typewriters, first you carriage return, moving the head back to the left, then you spool the paper forward one line.

Comment: btw, you have correct value of newline in Environment.NewLine

Comment: why don't you try with Environment.NewLine?

Answer (score 12):

Escape sequences have no meaning within actual string objects - only when the C# parser/compiler interprets them. You want to store an actual new line in your database field rather than the 4 characters "\r\n".

Answer (score 5):

It is likely that the \r\n is escaped, so the string actually returned would be equivalent to a string

`myString = "\\r\\n";`

So you would need to remove these extra slashes either when adding or removing from the database.

Though likely unrelated to your problem, the extra `\n` you have may cause viewing problems depending on the system, editor, etc.

You could replace all occurrences of \\n\\r, etc. using:

```
replacedString = myString.Replace("\\r\\n", "\r\n");
```

This should work to fix your problem.

Comment: +1 because even though Noldorin and Andrea were correct, they didn't point out how to actually get the escaped escape characters. And because I don't think you deserved to be at -1.

Answer (score 2):

Because `\r`, `\n`, etc. works only within a string in your C# code. If you read a string from a file, a database, or other things, they just get the verbatim values...

Comment: Yes. +1 to you too. Also, the <br/> tag works only if the email body is in html format.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `\r\n` with [`System.Environment.NewLine`](http://dotnetperls.com/newline) as the below may do work for you:

```
text.Replace("\r\n",  System.Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: Only if the e-mail body is html formatted, not in plain text.

Comment: The issue here isn't really to do with HTML, it's to do with the way strings are interpreted at compile-time and run-time.